# WebException not catching HTTP timeout

Tags: c#, webclient, httpwebresponse

I have a "try" function to access a page and grab data from it. Sometimes this page crashes for 4-5 minutes, probably due to me accessing it so often. To counter this I set up a catch:

```
try
{
WebClient web = new WebClient();
stream = web.OpenRead("http://website.org/who.php");
}
catch (WebException wex)
{
if (((HttpWebResponse)wex.Response).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
{
DONTDOSTUFF
}
{
DOSTUFF
}
}
```

However even when the page is down it is jumping to the "DOSTUFF" part and then failing, as there is no data caught to manipulate.

Any ideas? I am an extremely novice coder by the way, thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at what the StatusCode is coming back as. place a breakpoint on it.

Comment: Sorry super novice, an example?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/k80ex6de(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: The code never redirects to DONTDOSTUFF, therefore I can't put a breakpoint there to see the StatusCode as it just skips past it.

Comment: you CAN put a breakpoint on it. put a breakpoint on the IF condition itself in the catch block. But I can tell you, it wont go into the DONOTDOSTUFF block if the condition does NOT match.